# Expressjs Post-request is not getting recognized | 404-Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, http-status-code-404

I want to implement paypal to my website, but I am stuck with this. Always when I try to do a post request (also tried with postman), I dont get an answer which is just the normal 404 error-page. The console is showing no error, so I guess the post request is not getting recognized.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

**server.js**

```
//payment
app.post("/pay", (req, res) => {
    // payment data
    const create_payment_json = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/success",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": [{
                    "name": "product1",
                    "sku": "001",
                    "price": "350.00",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": 1
                }]
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "350.00"
            },
            "description": "test"
        }]
    };
    
    // create payment
    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, (error, payment) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log("payment not successful");
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            console.log("payment successful");
            console.log(payment);
        }
    })
    
})
```

**products.ejs**

```
<form action="/pay" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="add to cart" onclick="window.location.href='/pay'"/>
</form>
```

Comment: please remove `onclick="window.location.href='/pay'"/` from input and then try

Comment: it's not working either :/

Comment: @silliton in the browser (e.g. firefox/chrome) you should find a place where you can track  network request this can be handy for tracking it down - also if it does not work in postman then something is odd with the request not with the code itself - double check the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you need to make sure

1. Make sure you are sending the post request to the correct port, just incase your express server isn't hosting the actual site as well.  If it is then don't worry about the port
2. You can use js to send the request to prevent the page from refreshing.

```
    const form = document.querySelector('form')
    form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      const port = 3000 //make sure this is the port your express erver is listening on
      const formData = new FormData(e.target)
      const itemId = formData.get('itemId')// You can store the items id in the name attribute of an input
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:${port}/pay`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({itemId})
      })
    })
    const data = await response.json()

    console.log(data)  // The response you would get from the server
```

Comment: hm this code is not working for me, but thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I just get connected to the normal 404 - server not found page and nothing is happening